# Why Verdana font symbol: U+0022 is not the same like symbol: "

Tags: fonts, texworks

I have a OS Win7/64 and TeXLive 2012 fully updated.
TeXworks is set in preferences: UTF-8/Verdana

When I open a new document in TeXWorks Editor,
 I would like to get a symbol: " ,which means "dumb" quotation marks.
I do not need to print it, or use in program structure.
I would like to use keyboard sequence to get this symbol:( **"** )
I try to use keyboard: (left **Alt + 0022** on numerical keyboard) and, unfortunately:
 I got symbol: ( **Ţ** ).

but when I point this character from character table and choose this symbol ( " ) all is well.
Why do I have to use the **character table**, instead of pressing the right combination of keyboard?

I changed my previous question because was not very clear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You mean that this happens in the editor window of TeXworks?

Comment: TeXworks has no "clever quotation marks", it leaves everything on you and on the LaTeX engine. Have you tried to simply press the `"` button, or to copy-paste the symbol from this webpage?

Comment: It looks like you've got two (or more) separate accounts. The StackExchange staff can [merge them together for you](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Well, sometimes you couldn't use copy/paste, that way is not acceptable in this problem. I started to learn TeX (LateX) 2012 and I have a lots of questions, but all of friends don't know how to do it and I tried to ask here. This is my first questions, and even English language in not my mother tongue. If I did a lot of mess ... sorry<br/>
1. **egreg** ... yes I was ask about **TeXworks**.
2. **tohecz** I'm embarrassed not angry :-), I do a lot of mistakes

Comment: Chris, nobody is angry on you. We are asking for more details because we need them in order to be able to answer your question ;)

Comment: Is it that if you type " on the keyboard the editor types `` or '' instead?

Comment: @Chris Did you see my message about account merging?

Answer (score 1):

If you type cahracters in LaTeX they are interpreted by your input encoding package.
All your output is printed using some kind of font encoding.

For input problems try one of the following:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

[More about inputenc can be found in its manual.](http://www.tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/inputenc.pdf)

For output problems try one of the following:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
```

Additional information can be found on the web.

I am unsure what your problem is exactly, so here is a demo project to help you rephrase your question if your question is not answered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

The following example illustrates different quotation marks

This looks funny: ``Normal quotes differ left and rigth''. 

The left quotes can be created using this code textquotedblleft (\textquotedblleft). 

The rigth quotes can be created using textquotedblright (\textquotedblright).

Depending on your editor you can not type the following letter: "

\end{document}
```

Keep in mind that you should edit your original question to clarify what you wanted rather than using the answer button.